# Apify product variants on web page

Tags: apify

I need a little advice, because I am stuck with scraping one web page with Apify. I am using apify/web-scraper and basic scraping is already working (name, description, price etc.), but there are product variants on the page and I have no idea what would be the best method to scrape this data.

The product variant form looks like this:

```
<form class="qty add-to-basket add-to-basket-multi" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>white</td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <a href="" class="watch fancybox-modal">x</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alt-row">
                    <td>black</td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="tooltip" data-tip="6  pcs stock" data-tippos="top">
                            <input type="text" name="form_product_add_to_basket[count_2945]" value="0" class="count" data-id="2945" placeholder="ks" autocomplete="off" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>green</td>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <a href="" class="watch fancybox-modal">x</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see if product is not available there is no , otherwise there is.

In output I would like to get something like this (I describe with XML as later I need to convert Apify's output to XML):

```
<variants>
  <variant>
    <name>white</name>
    <stock>0</stock>
  </variant>
  <variant>
    <name>black</name>
    <stock>6</stock>
  </variant>
  <variant>
    <name>green</name>
    <stock>0</stock>
  </variant>
</variants>
```

Stock "6" for Black variant is coming from data-tip. I think this is somehow possible to get with regex.

My current code without variants:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const {
        request,
        log
    } = context;
    var result = [];
    if (!$(".product-desc").length) {
        return null;
    } else {
        const {
            url
        } = request;
        const category = url.split("?category=")[1];
        const title = $('.price-desc h1').text();
        var description = '';
        if ($('#product-desc li').text().length > 0) {
            description = $('#product-desc li').text()
        } else {
            description = $('.desc p:last').text()
        }
        const price = $('.wvat span:eq(0)').text();
        return {
            category,
            title,
            description,
            price
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `tr` as your item delimiter, so you can then extract from each `td`

```js
const variants = [];

$('tbody tr').each((_, el) => {
  const $el = $(el);
  variants.push({
    name: $el.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
    stock: parseInt($el.find('[data-tip]').attr('data-tip')) || $el.find('td:eq(1)').text().replace('x', '0'),
  });
})
```